Gedit restore minimap plugin stopped working with 24.04
First, Gedit removed the minimap, which was then restored with a plugin. Then, Ubuntu removed gedit altogether. Now, when I reinstall gedit with this plugin, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/.local/share/gedit/plugins/minimap/restore_minimap.py", line 105, in do_activate
    self.source_map = GtkSource.Map()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 130, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" % (
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.GtkSource' object has no attribute 'Map'


I've tried installing every gtksource-related package I can find, but then I start gedit and get the same error, with no minimap. So clearly, the plugin is looking for something it can't find and I can't figure out how to get it what it needs. Maybe I need to install a python module with pip3? I don't know. any help is appreciated.

The repo you link to seems to have been last updated 4 years ago. In all likelihood, the GTK API has changed since then and plugin simply doesn't work with the new API. Look for active fork, if one exists.
